# Libraries not found when running executable from R using "system" command

Tags: r, macos

Running MacOS Sierra (10.12.2), I have a program that can be executed successfully from terminal:

```
~$ /Users/pf/apps/cfm/bin/cfm-id

Usage: cfm-id.exe <spectrum_file> <id> <candidate_file> <num_highest> <ppm_mass_tol> <abs_mass_tol> <prob_thresh_for_prune> <param_filename> <config_filename> <score_type> <apply_postprocessing> <output_filename> <output_msp_or_mgf>
```

However, I need to run this program within R, using the `system()` command.  Doing so, I get the following error:

```
> system("/Users/pf/apps/cfm/bin/cfm-id")
dyld: Library not loaded: libFileParsers.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pf31/apps/cfm/bin/cfm-id
  Reason: image not found
>
```

So the program apparently can't find some of the necessary libraries when it is invoked as a system command from within R.

I've set my environment variables (e.g. DYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH, etc.) in an Renviron.site file and verified these using `Sys.getenv()`.

One hint: if I turn off the "rootless" SIP using `csrutil disable`, this program (and another that exhibits the same behavior) works fine both in Terminal and using `system("/Users/pf/apps/cfm/bin/cfm-id")` within R.  Unfortunately, if I turn off SIP, this breaks yet another necessary program, such that it will not run properly either in Terminal or within R.

Another hint: if I run the same program from Terminal using `sudo`, I get the same behavior as with the `system()` call within R:

```
$ sudo /Users/pf/apps/cfm/bin/cfm-id
dyld: Library not loaded: libFileParsers.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pf31/apps/cfm/bin/cfm-id
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Seems odd that the program would fail running as superuser.  I'm guessing there is an issue with permissions somewhere, but I don't know how to run it down.

Comment: You could try `system2` or `shell`.

Comment: Thanks, I did try `system2` and it has the same behavior.  Running `shell` doesn't work at all on my R:  `> shell("/Users/pf31/apps/cfm/bin/cfm-id")
Error: could not find function "shell"`